# Using a column with a boolean to access other columns

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like the following:

```
A B C
1 2 1
3 4 0
5 2 0
5 3 1
```

And would like to get the value from A if the value of C is 1 and the value of B if C is zero. How would I do this? Ultimately I'd like to end up with a vector with the values of A if C is one and B if C is 0 which would be `[1,4,2,5]`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean "from A is the value of C is 1 and from B if the value of C is 0", which makes sense given your intended output, I might use `Series.where`:

```
>>> df
   A  B  C
0  1  2  1
1  3  4  0
2  5  2  0
3  5  3  1
>>> df.A.where(df.C, df.B)
0    1
1    4
2    2
3    5
dtype: int64
```

which is read "make a series using values of A if the corresponding value of C is true, otherwise use the corresponding value of B".  Here since 1 is true we can just use `df.C`, but we could use `df.C == 1` or `df.C*5+3 < 4` or any other boolean Series.

Comment: Seems like it should work...having trouble getting it to return the right value though...

Comment: @goldisfine: Huh, that's strange.  Do you have a small example where it gives the wrong result?

Comment: @goldisfine You might have strings in `df`. If you do, the result will not be what @DSM shows above, it will be the original `df.A` `Series`.